# Read KML From Database

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, kml

I'm actually struggeling with a problem handling some kml files with google map in my Javascript application.

I wrote a method with that I'm reading a KML file from an URL or my local file system and storing the content as a String in a Database. Now i would like to activate layers that are stored in my db by clicking a button. Everything is fine up to here.

In every example i can find they are only using the url-attribute of a KmlLayer by passing an url to a KML-File.

like here:

```
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml',
    map: map
    });
```

But since my files are stored as Strings in my db I don't have an url to a file, only the content. I can't find a way to only pass the XML-String as content. 
Somebody here who can help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someday somebody will struggle with a similar problem. The solution was a little bit tricky. I needed to create a Blob with the content of my String. With the blob I created a file and packed it into an URL. This URL you can pass to your kml parser. I used https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3 for that.

```
vm.activeLayers.forEach(function(value, key) {
   var file = new Blob([value], {type: 'kml'})
   var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
   var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({
      map : map
   });
   myParser.parse(url);
})
```